# Reusing several report files in jenkins sonar plugin

Tags: ant, jenkins, sonarqube

I'm generating several XML report files via ant task (checkstyle, findbugs, macker, jacoco, ncss, classycle, etc.).

I want the to reuse the generated files in jenkins sonar plugin. Is there any way to do so?

I'm planning in setting the properties in the project specific `sonar-project.properties` file. But I can't find any of these options at codehaus documentation site.

Answer (score 1):

There's no point to reuse:

- checkstyle or findbugs reports as SonarQube also executes those tools
- ncss or classycle reports as it is SonarQube very job to compute those metrics

For JaCoCo, you can reuse reports if you don't want SonarQube to execute the unit tests again. See http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Code+Coverage+by+Unit+Tests+for+Java+Project.